# Can I programmatically force Windows RT to use 3g or HSPA?

Tags: networking, windows-8, cellular-network, windows-rt, mobile-broadband-api

I am doing some research on cellular connections like HSPA.  I have been searching for a Windows 8.1 API that will allow me to request the radio to use HSPA instead of LTE.

I have written an app for a window 8 phone and a windows 8.1 tablet. My area uses LTE, but I was able to disable the phone's LTE so it fell back to HSPA+. Unfortunately, I cannot find anything similar for this tablet (Nokia Lumia 2520).

So,  I haven't found anything and I am beginning to doubt that I will, but I thought I would check with others before declaring defeat.

Comment: This is not a SuperUser question, it's a valid SO programming question, but misleadingly written. He wants to know if there's an equivalent to IMbnRegistration::SetRegisterMode() for the Windows 8.1 WinRT APIs.